# jQuery .load() issue on IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue with `jQuery load()` not working on IE11.
I have a `<div>` in my html which I want to load a table to.
This table is in a separate file on a hard drive which only contains a table like so.

```
<table id="data">
<tr><td rowspan ="2">0</td><td rowspan="2">Text</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan ="2">0</td><td rowspan="2">Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>more text</td></tr>
</table>
```

So I try to load this table from my other html I have opened in IE11.

```
var dataDiv = $(this).parents("div:first");
dataDiv.load("html_table");
```

I tried to use some known workarounds like so:

```
$.ajax("html_table", {
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            dataDiv.html(data);
        },
        dataType:"html"
});
```

But still no success I'm not getting any errormessages so I'm wondering how I can work this out? Btw it does work in FireFox.

After trying this:

```
datadiv.load("html_table", function(response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        var msg = "Sorry there was an error: ";
                        $("#error").html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
                    }
                });
```

I can get hold of the err msg which says `Access denied` any possible reasonst for that?

```
console.log(response)
```

Just yields `'undefined'`

Comment: how are you loading the file? dataDiv.load("html_table"); doesn't have extension?

Comment: Yes it is a file without any extension containing some html code.

Comment: Can you try adding an extension? Maybe IE is picky.

Comment: I did try it after your first comment but no success sofar : (

Comment: Hard to say, especially when this is browser specific, did you console.log(dataDiv) to see if jQuery even got the proper container in IE11?

Comment: Your first 2 loads use `html_table` as the URL while the 3rd one uses `"details/" + filename` is that intentional or a typo?

Comment: Can you do a console.log of your response of get html file?

Comment: Have you tried adding the extension? It doesn't work for me without extension in chrome either, it works in both IE11 and Chrome. It just may be that the browser you tested with before happens to 'guess' the extension. The parameter for jquery load is 'url' not just file name so it may need the extension, also all examples in the docs have extension: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I did, it was already mentioned in first comment. It didn't work either way and I dont think thats the issue. Im not even sure if the issue is fixible though. But Im curious why it does work on FF.